# Extracting the minute difference between two datetime values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dt, minute

I want a column which records the difference between two times in terms of minutes....

>

```
 analysis['Duration in Minutes']=((analysis['DischEndTime'])-(analysis['DischStTime'])) 
> analysis['Duration in Minutes']=(analysis['Duration in Minutes']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
>>>>>>>0.761111
>(analysis['Duration in Minutes']).round(1)
>>>>>>>0.8
```

I want the output to be 0.7 instead of 0.8 instead of using the round function which rounds of the value to the next digit

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function to implement `ceil` function using the round function. Something this like:

```
In [137]: def my_floor(a, precision=0):
     ...:     return np.round(a - 0.5 * 10**(-precision), precision)
     ...:

In [138]: my_floor(0.786456,1)
Out[138]: 0.7
```